# How to delete record with composite primary keys using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, backend, composite-key

I'm trying to delete a record with two primary keys, using Eloquent - Laravel.

This is my model

```
class Like extends Model
{
    //protected $primaryKey = ['crdid', 'usrid'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Controller

```
try{
     $dellike = Like::where('crdid', '=', $like->crdid, 'and')
    ->where('usrid', '=', $like->usrid)->first();
                    $dellike->delete();
   }
   catch(Exception $e){
       return $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Table definition

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->biginteger('crdid');
        $table->biginteger('usrid');
        $keys = array('crdid', 'usrid');
        $table->primary($keys);
    });
```

However, it gives me the below error;

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `likes` where `id` is null)
```

I believe the 'id' is the default primary key used by Eloquent, but I'm not using it.

How should I define that, I'm not using the default primary key? or what is the correct way to delete the record with composite primary keys? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As [Laravel Eloquent Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#composite-primary-keys) says:

> Eloquent requires each model to have at least one uniquely identifying "ID" that can serve as its primary key. "Composite" primary keys are not supported by Eloquent models. However, you are free to add additional multi-column, unique indexes to your database tables in addition to the table's uniquely identifying primary key.

So you can't use some methods of eloquent.

But seeing your code, looks like you are trying to create a model for a relationship pivot table (many to many between user and `crd` (what is crd?! no reason to abreviatte here.)

Try defining a many to many relationship on your user and crd model.

Also laravel naming convention for key columns is: `model_name_id` for a model named `ModelName`

But, just to delete, you can skip the `first` in your query:

```
Like::where('crdid', '=', $like->crdid, 'and')
    ->where('usrid', '=', $like->usrid)->delete();
```

This happens because when you delete a model (your attempt) laravel uses the primary key field (defaults to id) as where condition. But manually querying, you are defining the where clauses of the delete.

Comment: Yes, the documentation states so, but I think there should be some workaround to achieve this.  and all I need is to delete the record using crdid and usrid. BTW usrid=userid, crdid=cardid. cards liked by users - many-to-many as you said. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create additionnal column named id in the table as unique with auto-increment option. Eloquent will use it to delete each row with delete function.
Example with **Laravel 5.5** :

```
$logement = Logement::findOrFail($id);
$commodites = Commodites_logement::all()->where('logement_id','=',$logement->id);
foreach ($commodites as $commodite) {
   $commodite->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling to delete a row with a composite primary key, here is an easy approach (regardless of your model class definition). You don't need to add an auto incremented column to your tables if they already have a "natural" unique key. Creating an additional int/bigInt column for this purpose is overkilling and consumes more resources unnecessarily.

In this example the table **category** has a key defined as `[catId, userId]`.

In my JS file, the request is made like so:

```
axios.delete(`/category/${catId}/${userId}`)
```

I am using axios for simplicity, but you could use the fetch API, jQuery, Alpine or whatever you like.

The method in my controller file:

```
   public function destroy($catId, $userId) {
      $result = $this->category->destroy($catId, $userId);
      return $result;
   }
```

The method in my model class:

```
   /**
    * Marks the row, with the given key, as deleted.
    * 
    * @param int $catId  The category id.
    * @param int $userId  The user id.
    */
   public function destroy($catId, $userId) {
      $this->userId = $userId;
      $this->categoryId = $catId;
      $query = "UPDATE category SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE userId = ? AND categoryId = ?";
      return DB::delete($query, [$this->userId, $this->categoryId]);
   }
```

My route is defined as follows:

```
Route::delete('/category/{catId}/{userId}', [categoryController::class, 'destroy']);
```

The model class method only marks the row as deleted (soft deletes managed on my own for I don't like Laravel way). This code is actually working as expected.

I hope this example may be helpful to anyone.